# Python has stopped working(3.7)while installing window service

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, service, pywin32

I am creating window service using python(**python3.7.0**).

```
import pythoncom
import win32serviceutil
import win32service
import win32event
import servicemanager
import socket
import time
import sys

class BRSService(win32serviceutil.ServiceFramework):
    _svc_name_ = 'BRS'
    _svc_display_name_ = 'BRS'

    def __init__(self, args):
        win32serviceutil.ServiceFramework.__init__(self, args)
        self.hWaitStop = win32event.CreateEvent(None, 0, 0, None)

        socket.setdefaulttimeout(60)
        self.isAlive = True

    def SvcStop(self):
        self.isAlive = False
        self.ReportServiceStatus(win32service.SERVICE_STOP_PENDING)
        win32event.SetEvent(self.hWaitStop)

    def SvcDoRun(self):
        self.ReportServiceStatus(win32service.SERVICE_RUNNING)
        self.isAlive = True
        servicemanager.LogMsg(servicemanager.EVENTLOG_INFORMATION_TYPE, 
                              servicemanager.PYS_SERVICE_STARTED, (self._svc_name_, ''))
        self.main()
        win32event.WaitForSingleObject(self.hWaitStop, win32event.INFINITE)

    def main(self):
        #i = 0
        while self.isAlive: 
            print ("Service alive")
            time.sleep(86400)

        #pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    if len(sys.argv) == 1:
        servicemanager.Initialize()
        servicemanager.PrepareToHostSingle(BRSService)
        servicemanager.StartServiceCtrlDispatcher()
    else:
        win32serviceutil.HandleCommandLine(BRSService)
```

So when I run the command **"BRS.py install"**.
The window message is coming **"python has stopped working"**.
Looks like some problem while calling **"win32serviceutil.HandleCommandLine"** function.

Comment: *Python* 32 or 64 bit? Have you tried with an older (and more stable) version?

Comment: 64bit, where can I find older stable version?

Comment: https://www.python.org/downloads

Answer (score 1):

i meet the same problem, and i use the same as you ,Python 3.7 64bit, meet stop working also.
now i found if use Python 3.6.4 64bit. no error raise. you can try.

Comment: 3.7 64bit, meet stop working also.  3.6.4 64bit works for me also